Unexpected null value in type-safe navigation Jetpack Compose
This is a snippet of my navigation graph:
MyApp.kt
navigation<MainApp>(startDestination = Home) {
                composable<Home> {
                    atHomeScreen = true
                    HomeScreen(
                        onClick = { categoryId ->
                            navController.navigate(Items(categoryId = categoryId))
                        }
                    )
                }

                composable<Items>(
                ) { backStackEntry ->
                    val categoryId: String = backStackEntry.toRoute()
                    atHomeScreen = false
                    ItemsScreen(categoryId)
                }
                   //...
}


As you can see, I am passing the categoryId, which is a non-null String from Home to Items. But still, the categoryId gets assigned a null value somehow. Please help me debug this.
Note:
HomeScreen.kt
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    onClick: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val categories by viewModel.itemCategories.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
    ) {
        categories.forEach { category ->
            DataCard(
                title = category.title,
                imageUrl = category.imageUrl,
                onCardClick = {
                    onClick(category._id.toHexString())
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

Routes.kt
@Serializable
data class Items(val categoryId: String)    //definition of Items route


Can you include the entire stack trace of the error you are getting?

toRoute() returns the type that was passed when calling the navigate() method. In this case, you passed Items, so toRoute() should return Items. But, since you defined categotyId as a String and not as Items, the toRoute() cannot return this type

When you get the passed parameters from the backStackEntry, you should get the "Items" not the categoryId, not like the old way of getting the parameter, now you get the object or the class itself.it should be like that:
val items: Items = backStackEntry.toRoute()

